# Object is not saved in spock integration test

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, integration-testing, spock

I have a Token entity:

```
class Token {
    /**
     * Constants for various namespaces
     */
    public static final String NS_PASSWORD_RESET = "pass-reset";

    /**
     * A simple string unlimited in content that defines a scope of the token
     */
    String namespace

    /**
     * This fields holds an identifier for anything specific that the process might need 
     */
    Long identifier

    /**
     * The actual token itself
     */
    String token

    Timestamp dateCreated
    Timestamp lastUpdated
    Timestamp expiration

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and a service class with a following method:

```
def creareNewToken(String ns, int timeout) {
        def token = new Token()

        token.setNamespace(ns)
        token.setToken(this.generateToken(15))

        //persist the object
        token.save(flush: true)

        return token
    }
```

I created an integration test for the service class:

```
class TokenServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    TokenService tokenService

    def "test creareNewToken"() {
        when:
        def token = tokenService.creareNewToken(Token.NS_PASSWORD_RESET, 60)

        then:
        token instanceof Token
        token.getNamespace() == Token.NS_PASSWORD_RESET
        token.getToken().length() == 15
        token.getDateCreated() == ''
    }
}
```

When I execute the test, I get:

```
Failure:  test
creareNewToken(com.iibs.security.TokenServiceIntegrationSpec)
    |  Condition not satisfied:
    token.getDateCreated() == ''
    |     |                |
    |     null             false
    com.iibs.security.Token : (unsaved)
        at com.iibs.security.TokenServiceIntegrationSpec.test creareNewToken(TokenServiceIntegrationSpec.groovy:31)
```

What could be the reason for this problem? Is seems like the object is actually not saved, and, of coarse, the **dateCreated** is not populated as well. My question is why it is not saved? I have number of other tests that build in a similar way, and they work without any issue.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two fields (identifier and expiration) which you are not setting. By default every field is not nullable. Try adding:

```
assert token.save(...)
```

To check if your object is really being saved.

If you want them to accept null as a value you need to specify it in your constraints

```
static constraints = { 
identifier nullable: true
expiration nullable: true 
}
```

Comment: It did not help. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `failOnError:true` to the options on save, if only for debugging purposes. The resulting stack trace will usually point out if a field is not set, etc.

```
def creareNewToken(String ns, int timeout) {
    def token = new Token()

    token.setNamespace(ns)
    token.setToken(this.generateToken(15))

    //persist the object
    token.save(flush: true, failOnError:true)//this will throw an error if save does not occur

    return token
}
```